# Combine map, filter and some in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm doing an application in Angular 6 and I want to filter an array of Objects to find if one of them has the X property equal to X value.

My array of Objects:

```
users = [
  {
    "id": "3myuB3YYlHNK5m4WZC7CxrX3MvA3",
    "identificationMethod": "cedula",
    "identificationNumber": "23447847457",
  },
  {
    "id": "7ruDZvmsvTVZfA59nfB7SU65gwi1",
    "identificationMethod": "cedula",
    "identificationNumber": "23232323232",
  },
  {
    "id": "8IpMYYfy5dhBaR7QoQz4mXXLE1T2",
    "identificationMethod": "passport",
    "identificationNumber": "src34323",
  }
]
```

I want to find all the users who has `identificationMethod` equal to passport, then I want to know if there is one of these users who has `identificationNumber` equal to 23232323232.

Right now, I have this snippet working:

```
const equalUsers: UserId[] = this.users.filter(user => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod);

const isUnique: boolean = equalUsers.map(user => user.identificationNumber).some(value => value === identificationNumber);

          (isUnique)
            ? console.log('Is unique')
            : console.log('Is not unique');
```

I want to achieve the same but, combining `.map()`, `.filter()` and `.some()` (or any other method available) in just one line.

I have tried:

```
const isUnique = this.users.filter(user => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod)
            .some(user => user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber);
```

- Do I need to use `.map()` here?.
- There is a better way to do this?

My goal is to achieve the same as the first snippet but, shorter, faster and understandable. I'm confused and I am not sure if I need to use `.map()` first or is not necessary.

Comment: `this.users.some(user => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod && user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the condition in your Array methods.

```js
const users = [{
    "id": "3myuB3YYlHNK5m4WZC7CxrX3MvA3",
    "identificationMethod": "passport",
    "identificationNumber": "23447847457",
  },
  {
    "id": "3myuB3YYlHNK5m4WZC7CxrX3MvA3",
    "identificationMethod": "passport",
    "identificationNumber": "23447847457",
  },
  {
    "id": "8IpMYYfy5dhBaR7QoQz4mXXLE1T2",
    "identificationMethod": "passport",
    "identificationNumber": "src34323",
  }
];

const identificationMethod = "passport";
const identificationNumberDuplicate = "23447847457";
const identificationNumberUnique = "src34323";
const identificationNumberDoesNotExist = "xxx";

const test = (identificationMethod, identificationNumber) => {
  const found = users.filter(user => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod &&
    user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber);
  const exists = found.length > 0;
  const isUnique = found.length === 1;

  console.log("Exists: " + exists, "Unique: " + isUnique);
};

test(identificationMethod, identificationNumberUnique);
test(identificationMethod, identificationNumberDuplicate);
test(identificationMethod, identificationNumberDoesNotExist);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Also, the answer that jcalz added below my question works too. Nice logic to achieve the same and also to test it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is needed to be fleshed out into a full answer, but I'd suggest doing this:

```
this.users.some(user => 
  user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod && 
  user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber
);
```

Assuming you've got a finite-length array `array` that doesn't throw errors when you read it, a one-argument function `f`, and a one-argument [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) `p` (a predicate is a function that returns `true` or `false`), the following expressions should always give you the same results:

```
array.map(f).some(p); // turn all x into f(x), then check that at least one p(f(x)) is true
array.some(x => p(f(x))); // check that at least one p(f(x)) is true
```

That is, you can [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) `p` and `f` into a new predicate `q` and just do `array.some()` on that.  You've already figured that one out, since in your case

`f` is `user => user.identificationNumber`,
`p` is `id => id === identificationNumber`,
so `q` is `user => user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber`

Additionally, the following should always give you the same results:

```
array.filter(p).some(q); // of the x where p(x) is true, is there an x where q(x) is true?
array.some(x => p(x) && q(x)); // is there an x where both p(x) and q(x) are true?
```

That is, you are combining the two predicates `p` and `q` into a new predicate `r` via [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).  Performing that transformation on your above callbacks:

`p` is `user => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod`,
`q` is `user => user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber`,
so `r` is `u => user.identificationMethod === identificationMethod && user.identificationNumber === identificationNumber`

Note that although they give the same results they do not perform the same steps.  The original version you have, `array.filter(p).map(f).some(q)`, will end up performing `p` on every single element `x` of the array, then performing `f` on all those that pass the test, and finally performing `q` on all of those `f(x)` until it finds one that passes the test.  But the new version, `array.some(r)` will only perform `p` and `f` on the elements until one passes the `q` test.  If the very first element of the array passes the test, the latter method will only ever look at this first element, while the former method will go through all of them.

This probably isn't a big deal in terms of performance unless your arrays are absolutely huge, and it isn't a big deal in terms of behavior unless your arrays have [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) when you read from them (like, maybe you use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that makes changes when you read from it).

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!